# C++ Ubuntu. Multiple undefined references compiling with FFMPEG libs

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I installed FFMPEG libraries on Ubuntu 12.10 and headers as it is described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuideQuantal) .

In my C++ application which uses FFMPEG when I am compiling (gcc) I am getting this :

> /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libfaac.o): In function
>   `Faac_encode_frame': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:179: undefined
>   reference to`faacEncEncode' /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libfaac.o):
>   In function `Faac_encode_close': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:52:
>   undefined reference to`faacEncClose'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libfaac.o): In function
>   `Faac_encode_init': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:78: undefined
>   reference to`faacEncOpen' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:88:
>   undefined reference to `faacEncGetCurrentConfiguration'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:139: undefined reference to`
>   faacEncGetDecoderSpecificInfo' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:153:
>   undefined reference to `faacEncSetConfiguration'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): In function`
>   aac_encode_close': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:99:
>   undefined reference to `aacEncClose'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): In function`
>   aac_encode_frame': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:344:
>   undefined reference to `aacEncEncode'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): In function`
>   aac_encode_init': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:116:
>   undefined reference to `aacEncOpen'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:125: undefined reference to`
>   aacEncoder_SetParam' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:132:
>   undefined reference to `aacEncoder_SetParam'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:140: undefined reference to`
>   aacEncoder_SetParam' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:160:
>   undefined reference to `aacEncoder_SetParam'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:167: undefined reference to`
>   aacEncoder_SetParam'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o):/root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:185:
>   more undefined references to `aacEncoder_SetParam' follow
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libfdk-aacenc.o): In function`
>   aac_encode_init': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:263:
>   undefined reference to `aacEncEncode'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:269: undefined reference to`
>   aacEncInfo' /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o): In function
>   `mp3lame_encode_frame': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:204:
>   undefined reference to`lame_encode_buffer_float'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:188: undefined reference to
>   `lame_encode_buffer' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:191:
>   undefined reference to`lame_encode_buffer_int'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:210: undefined reference to
>   `lame_encode_flush' /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o): In
>   function`mp3lame_encode_close':
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:88: undefined reference to
>   `lame_close' /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o): In function`
>   mp3lame_encode_init': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:100:
>   undefined reference to `lame_init'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:104: undefined reference to`
>   lame_set_num_channels' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:105:
>   undefined reference to `lame_set_mode'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:108: undefined reference to`
>   lame_set_in_samplerate' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:109:
>   undefined reference to `lame_set_out_samplerate'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:113: undefined reference to`
>   lame_set_quality' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:115: undefined
>   reference to `lame_set_quality'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:119: undefined reference to`
>   lame_set_VBR' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:120: undefined
>   reference to `lame_set_VBR_quality'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:123: undefined reference to`
>   lame_set_brate' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:127: undefined
>   reference to `lame_set_bWriteVbrTag'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:130: undefined reference to`
>   lame_set_disable_reservoir' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:133:
>   undefined reference to `lame_init_params'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:139: undefined reference to`
>   lame_get_encoder_delay' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libmp3lame.c:142:
>   undefined reference to `lame_get_framesize'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_wb_decode_close': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:363:
>   undefined reference to `D_IF_exit'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_nb_decode_frame': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:122:
>   undefined reference to `Decoder_Interface_Decode'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_wb_decode_frame': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:352:
>   undefined reference to `D_IF_decode'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_nb_encode_frame': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:267:
>   undefined reference to `Encoder_Interface_Encode'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_wb_decode_init': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:318:
>   undefined reference to `D_IF_init'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_nb_encode_close': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:222:
>   undefined reference to `Encoder_Interface_exit'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_nb_decode_close': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:86:
>   undefined reference to `Decoder_Interface_exit'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_nb_encode_init': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:205:
>   undefined reference to `Encoder_Interface_init'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libopencore-amr.o): In function`
>   amr_nb_decode_init': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libopencore-amr.c:73:
>   undefined reference to `Decoder_Interface_init'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libspeexdec.o): In function`
>   libspeex_decode_frame': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:139:
>   undefined reference to `speex_bits_remaining'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:147: undefined reference to`
>   speex_bits_read_from' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:152:
>   undefined reference to `speex_decode_int'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:140: undefined reference to`
>   speex_bits_peek_unsigned' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:158:
>   undefined reference to `speex_decode_stereo_int'
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libspeexdec.o): In function`
>   libspeex_decode_close': /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:169:
>   undefined reference to `speex_bits_destroy'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:170: undefined reference to`
>   speex_decoder_destroy' /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libspeexdec.o): In
>   function `libspeex_decode_init':
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:48: undefined reference to`
>   speex_packet_to_header' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:67:
>   undefined reference to `speex_header_free'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:82: undefined reference to`
>   speex_lib_get_mode' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:100:
>   undefined reference to `speex_bits_init'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:101: undefined reference to`
>   speex_decoder_init' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:110:
>   undefined reference to `speex_std_stereo_request_handler'
>   /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:113: undefined reference to`
>   speex_decoder_ctl' /root/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libspeexdec.c:43:
>   undefined reference to `speex_nb_mode'

and more ....

When I compile I link against these libs:

**-lfaac -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lavfilter  -lswscale**

What is the problem ?

Comment: Try reordering the libraries. Start by putting `-lavcodec` at the back.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the correct order?Positioning lavcodec to be last hasn't helped.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the ffmpeg library that comes with Ubuntu and see how it is compiled there: apt-get source ffmpeg

Comment: No idea. The dependencies are only scanned once, in order, from left to right. You could try saying the entire set of libraries twice, like `-lfaac -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lfaac -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to compile.For those interested:

First I disabled some modules (which I don't really use) :

./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame \
  **--disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libspeex** --enable-**librtmp --disable-libtheora** \
  --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3

Then I linked the rest of dependencies in this order:

**-lavformat -lavcodec -lfaac -lmp3lame -lfdk-aac -lvpx -lx264 -lavdevice -lyasm -lavutil -lswscale -lrtmp -lvorbisenc -lva**